# How can I show the wallpaper in my app?

Tags: ios

So if you use Apple Music on iOS 10, you can see the homescreen wallpaper in the background of the statusbar:

[image: desc]

I want to do this in my app when a modal view is displayed, but I think this is a private API.

Can I do this in my app? And if so, how?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no public API available

Comment: You can't due to being able to then screenshot the background of a user. It's only apple that can set their window background to clear.

Comment: Do you want to change the status bar color??